# Selecting children nodes that is not h3 from parents that are not the first two children of a grandparent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

`container` is my main division, with `process` following. `process` consists of many `parent_node`s and each `parent_node` has different children (all has `h3`, however).

I would like to select children nodes that is not h3 from parents that are not the first two children of a grandparent.

What I've tried:

```
$(('.container > .process > .parent_node.slice(2) > :not(h3)')
```

How do I correct the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a simple `nth-child` should do the trick:

```
.container > .process > .parent_node:nth-child(n + 3) > :not(h3)
```

Comment: What does `n` mean here? And wouldn't `nth-child(n + 3)` mean only one `.parent_node` is selected?

Comment: `n + 3` is an expression that will match 3rd child and onwards (`n` must be typed as-is).

Comment: I see. Is there a reverse sort of CSS selector which, instead of selecting all except first two of each list, selects the first two of each list, like `(-n + 3)`?

Comment: Yes... `(-n + 2)` will do just that. You can test the expression here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/salmanarshad2000/demos/v1.0.4/css/nth-child-arguments-test.html

Comment: I see! That link is really helpful :-D

One final thing, I don't think I get what you meant by the list of ALL and EACH there fully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186834/discussion-between-salman-a-and-wealthy-player).